# Spring: Is it possible to place your filter mappings in application-security.xml instead of web.xml?

Tags: spring, web-applications

Is it possible to place your filter mapping in application-security.xml instead of web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Filter mapping is the way to glue Spring security with your servlet container/request handling. Without filter Spring security would know nothing about your requests.

You can try [web fragments](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/servlet3/assembling_webfragments.shtml) if you can't modify `web.xml`, see alsp [[1]](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mode/archive/2008/05/servlet_30_plug.html), [[2]](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_101_applying_servlet_3).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you have an example of how this is done or how you do that?

Comment: @stackoverflow: added some links to my answer with examples.